# Google App Script unzip a Gmail attachment before appending the unzipped CSV to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, email-attachments, unzip

I am completely new to Google App Script.  I'm trying to build something because I can't find a Google add-on that does exactly what I want.  But I have no idea what I'm doing!  Is anyone willing to help?

Goal:  I need a script that will identify when a daily email with a particular subject line and from a particular sender arrives in my gmail inbox.  The email always has a .zip attachement.  I need the script to 1) unzip the attached - which gives me a csv file, and then I need 2) the unzipped csv file to be appended to a Google Sheet.

Here is where I am starting with someone else's script:

```
function importDailyCallVolumes() {
  // Get the newest Gmail thread based on sender and subject
  var gmailThread = GmailApp.search("from:UCCX.Corpemail@company.com subject:\"Daily Call Vols\"", 0, 1)[0];
  
  // Get the attachments of the latest mail in the thread.
  var attachments = gmailThread.getMessages()[gmailThread.getMessageCount() - 1].getAttachments();
  
  // Here I need to add some code to unzip the attachment - how?

  // Get and and parse the CSV from the unzipped attachment
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(attachments[0].getDataAsString());
  return csv;
}
```

Thank you so much to anyone willing to help an App Script newbie!

Comment: I believe that I've read about a trigger that operates on received emails but as I recall it has to be set up in the cloud console.  I've never used it.

Comment: Theres an  unzip in utilities

Comment: Thanks Cooper - I've added this now

// Unzip attachment
  var zipblob = attachments[0].getBlob();
  var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob);
  var unzipstr = unzipblob[0].getDataAsString();
  DocsList.createFile('test.txt',unzipstr);

But I get this error:  

Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBlob' of undefined importDailyCallVolumes @ Code.gs:8

What does it mean?  I've declared all variables so not sure why they are undefined.

Comment: The attachments[0] must be undefined

Answer (score 0):

#### Append CSV zipped file to Active sheet

```
function appendzipcsv() {
  const ibts = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (let i = 0; i < ibts.length; i++) {
    let ms = ibts[i].getMessages();
    for (let j = 0; j < ms.length; j++) {
      let a = ms[j].getAttachments();
      if (a && a.length > 0) {
        Logger.log(JSON.stringify(a));
        if (a[0].getContentType() == MimeType.ZIP) {
          let s = Utilities.unzip(a[0].copyBlob())[0].getDataAsString();
          Logger.log(s);
          let vs = Utilities.parseCsv(s);
          let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
          let sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
          sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Utilities.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String,Char))